# android studio debug rest api

Tags: android, retrofit

I am a noob to android developer.
I am using android studio to develop app.I am using retrofit to interact with server rest api.it seems to have some question, when I use android studio avd to debug the rest api request and response, I can't see the response body on android studio logcat, event the resposne status is 200.
but when I debug the rest api with the real mobile it will get response correctly.

I want to know if android studio can't debug the rest api and if it can, how should I use it.

Addition, I debug the rest api use retrofit okttp interceptor.

Comment: add your full code

Answer (score 0):

try this code 
add below dependency into gradle file

```
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.1'



public class ApiClient {
private final static String BASE_URL = "https://simplifiedcoding.net/demos/";

public static ApiClient apiClient;
private Retrofit retrofit = null;

public static ApiClient getInstance() {
    if (apiClient == null) {
        apiClient = new ApiClient();
    }
    return apiClient;
}

//private static Retrofit storeRetrofit = null;

public Retrofit getClient() {
    return getClient(null);
}


private Retrofit getClient(final Context context) {

    HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
    interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
    OkHttpClient.Builder client = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
    client.readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    client.writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    client.connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    client.addInterceptor(interceptor);
    client.addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public okhttp3.Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request request = chain.request();

            return chain.proceed(request);
        }
    });

    retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .client(client.build())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();


    return retrofit;
}
```

}

it show all log api url,response etc.